# Laravel Route Not Found Error in Pest Test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-package, orchestra

I’m currently developing a Laravel package and writing tests for my API routes using Pest and orchestra/testbench. However, I’m encountering an issue where my routes cannot be found when running the test.

Can someone

Here’s the route I’m trying to test: `/api/my-web/matches`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

test('', function () {
    Config::set([
        "football.route_prefix" => "api/football",
        "football.middlewares" => []
    ]);

    $response = $this->getJson('/api/my-web/matches');

    dd($response->json());
});
```

**Error:**

```
array:1 [
  "message" => "The route /api/my-web/matches could not be found."
]
```

**Pest setup:**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Test Case
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The closure you provide to your test functions is always bound to a specific PHPUnit test
| case class. By default, that class is "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase". Of course, you may
| need to change it using the "uses()" function to bind a different classes or traits.
|
*/

// uses(Tests\TestCase::class)->in('Feature');
use Alex\Football\tests\FootballTestCase;

uses(FootballTestCase::class)->in(__DIR__);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Expectations
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When you're writing tests, you often need to check that values meet certain conditions. The
| "expect()" function gives you access to a set of "expectations" methods that you can use
| to assert different things. Of course, you may extend the Expectation API at any time.
|
*/

expect()->extend('toBeOne', function () {
    return $this->toBe(1);
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Functions
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| While Pest is very powerful out-of-the-box, you may have some testing code specific to your
| project that you don't want to repeat in every file. Here you can also expose helpers as
| global functions to help you to reduce the number of lines of code in your test files.
|
*/

function something()
{
    // ..
}
```

**Package TestCase:**

```
<?php

namespace Alex\Football\tests;

use Alex\Football\FootballServiceProvider;
use Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase;

class FootballTestCase extends TestCase
{
    protected function getPackageProviders($app): array
    {
        return [
            FootballServiceProvider::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

**PhpUnit.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" backupGlobals="false" colors="true" processIsolation="false" stopOnFailure="false" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/11.0/phpunit.xsd" cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache" backupStaticProperties="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Package">
      <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <source>
    <include>
      <directory>src/</directory>
    </include>
  </source>
</phpunit>
```

**ServiceProvider:**

```
<?php

namespace Alex\Football;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FootballServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(): void {
        //publish config
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/../config/football.php' => config_path('football.php'),
        ], "football.config");

        //load api routes
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {}
}
```

Any help on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. If someone could possibly assist me in troubleshooting this, I would be very thankful. Thank you!

Comment: Try running php artisan route:clear to clear the route cache.